# Odd behavior of QListView

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a c++ qt project where I have two windows. One of them is called `MainWindow` and another one is `StartingWindow`.

When `MainWindow` starts, I am running a `QProcess` to run `pacman -Q` to get the list of installed packages. Then using a `QByteArray`, I'm obtaining the `stdout`, and then converting it to a `QStringList` to generate a `QSortFilterProxyModel` and setting this to a `QListView` in `MainWindow`.

This approach works fine. But if I start `MainWindow` from `StartingWindow`, it behaves oddly. The list of apps which is supposed to be shown is incomplete. About 100 of the apps from the start is missing.

Any help is greatly appreciated. If you any part of my code, just let me know.

**Code for starting QProcess:**

```
 QStringList args;
 args << "-Q";
 commandProcess.start("pacman",args);
```

**Code for getting it's stdout:**

```
QStringList applist;
model=new QStringListModel(this);
proxyModel=new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);

QByteArray cmdoutput=commandProcess.readAllStandardOutput();
QString txtoutput=cmdoutput;
applist=txtoutput.split("\n");
model->setStringList(applist);

QStringList arguments=commandProcess.arguments();
QString args=arguments.join("");
 ui->installedApps->setModel(proxyModel);
```

Comment: I think no one can help you without posting at least the part of code where you start the `QProcess` and read from its stdout in the main window

Comment: @Mike added the code

Comment: where are you starting the `QProcess`? is it in the constructor for `MainWindow`? and where are you reading the stdout?

Comment: just after where I am setting up the ui, the process is started. And the output is read in another function.